# Output contents to two different files

Tags: linux, shell

How to redirect the out of ls /tmp command to more than one file

i.e, the out put needs to be on ls /tmp > a.txt and b.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `tee`:

```
# This way you will see the output.
ls /tmp | tee file1.txt file2.txt

# With this line you won't.
ls /tmp | tee file1.txt file2.txt >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use tee `ls /tmp  | tee -a a.txt b.txt`

edit: okay DarkDust wars faster :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other suggested methods: you can also just cp the output file after executing the ls.